# python selenium chrome download item from 'Frames'

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I want to download images from a webpage.

For example, if you open `https://stackoverflow.com` in chrome and then go to `Developer tool -> application -> Frames -> top -> Images`. You will find an image called `robot.svg`.

[image]

I can simply download this item by right click it and `save image`. However, I do not know how to download it with code.

I tried to get the image URL of the true images I want to download and download it with `requests`; however, it will return `403`.

I would also be appreciated if you can download this type of image (requires login, cookie, header, add more verification) in other methods.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the 403, most likely because the page is behind an authorization. You can make a request with the Login authorization and other headers like this:

```
import requests
import base64

userpass = 'replace_with_a_real_username' + ':' + 'replace_with_a_real_password'
baseauth = base64.b64encode(userpass.encode()).decode()

def save_file_from_an_url(url):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': "Basic %s" % baseauth,
        'AnotherHeader': 'value of that header'
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open('robot.svg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)

save_file_from_an_url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/home/robot.svg?v=dfa16a330cbd")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Some websites have multiple authorization checks which may take a long time to figure them all out. I want to find a universal way to download these images quickly. Thanks for your help!